# How to find Maximum value from 5 inputs by user?

Tags: c++

If a user inputs five values, how to find a maximum value between those 5?

```
cin >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e;
```

In this code we took 5 inputs. Now we have to find maximum value entered by the user.

Comment: Bro what I know is this by using loops. But I have to store these 5 integers differently to continue my problems. That's why I just showed this. While using loops we have to do this using one variable only.

Comment: I didn't meant though. Just trying to say first  try and come. Don't put your HM problems here. Well, let me give you one hint. Take entries in an array and sort that array in increasing or decrasing order. Remaining upto you.

Comment: Personally I find "bro" disrespectful, too. It's slang for special kind of people.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this answer

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cin>>a[i];
    }
    //Assume that a[0] is greatest value
    greatest = a[0];
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      if (a[i] > greatest) {
         greatest = a[i];
    }
    }
      printf("Greatest of ten numbers is %d", greatest);
      return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should be fine, typing on mobile so excuse any syntax errors.

```
std::vector<int> user_inputs;

while (user_inputs.size() < 5)
{
    int user_arg = 0;

    std::cout << "Please enter number " << (user_inputs.size() + 1) << ": ";
    std::cin >> user_arg;

    user_inputs.push_back(user_arg);
}

std::sort(user_inputs.begin(), user_inputs.end());

std::cout << "Lowest value entered:" << user_inputs.front() << std::endl;
std::cout << "Highest value entered:" << user_inputs.back() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

The Best Code I required Was

```
int a,b,c,d,e,max;
cin>>a;
max=a;
cin>>b;
if(b>max)
max=b;
cin>>c;
if(c>max)
max=c;
cin>>d;
if(d>max)
max=d;
cin>>e;
if(e>max)
max=e;
```

Answer (score 0):

The most idiomatic way would be to use [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) which does exactly what the name suggests. For that, values would need to be in a container, for which e.g. a brace-initialized `std::array` (for a known number of 5 values), or a `std::vector` (for unknown-number of values) will do.

The next best way would be sorting as suggested by @Dilusha, but of course there's partial sorting and `std::nth_element`, which will do less work for the same net result (as you do not really need a sorted sequence, you only need **one element** in the right place -- a complete sort is thus "wasteful").

Or, you can of course just use a sequence of `result = std::max(result, a [b c d... whatever])` which isn't very elegant, but will do the job just fine. Remember to initialize `result` to zero to begin with.